# Solved matrix equation- verification

Tags: determinant, matrix-equations

Solving this matrix equation 
$\det \begin{vmatrix} x & 3+x & 3+x\\ 2 & x+3 & 6\\ 3 & 4 & x+6 \end{vmatrix}$
I got stuck in this polynomial equation: $x^3+4x^2-16x+15=0$
This seems wrong to me because the value I got for x is kinda wrong and probably I may have use a wrong approach to get here. Pls I need a hint or guide to proceed

Comment: it's correct...the polynomial is correct.. $|A|=(x-2)(x^2+5x-10)+(x-1)(x+5)$

Comment: @chinnapparaj how do I apply rule of sarrus in this context?

Comment: @isham what will be my value of x then, if its correct.

Comment: @isham what will be my value of x then, if its correct.

Comment: @MichaelUmande   one real solution...https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x3%2B4x2%E2%88%9216x%2B15%3D0